# HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/test

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to do work in simple servlet example using notepad but it's showing an error like this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/test
type Status report
message /FirstServlet/test
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

i'm running this into eclipse still showing the same error:

[image: here]

Is that a window's problem ? I'm using windows 8.

Tell me to fix the error,here is my classpath which i set in Environment variables options:

```
Classpath: D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib\servlet-api.jar
java_home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

My code for TestServlet.java follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 
    }
}
```

and here is my source code for Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>MyWebApp</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>bla.TestServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and here is a structure of my folder where i saved my file as:

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.47
|
|
Webapps(folder)
|
|
|    (project name)
|==FirstServlet==>>WEB-INF
                      |
                      |
                      |==classes(folder)==>>bla(folder)==>>TestServlet.class(compiled file) and TestServlet.java(source code for servlet)
                      |
                      |==lib(folder)==>>servlet-api.jar (api of servlet where i copied)
                      |
                      |==web.xml (xml file)
```

My url:

i'm accessing the url like this `http://localhost:8080/FirstServlet/test`

here is an image which showing an error:

[image]

Comment: 404 is a 'File not found' response. Wherever you're putting your file, it's not in the web root of the server. Make sure you're putting it in the right place.

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be a `servlet-api.jar` in the `WEB-INF` directory of a webapp, it should be in tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: sorry stupid keyboard :p i edited now still giving an error now.. please hep!

Comment: i edited "bla.TestServlet" and "doget" still giving an error..:( how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Mike W@ will you please describe me where to save my folder.?

Comment: here is an image which showing an error: http://postimg.org/image/lyta5v0b5/

Comment: i'm running this into eclipse still showing the same error [here](http://postimg.org/image/z4w7s1u1d/) is that a window's problem ? i'm using windows 8..

Comment: Apart from  Sotirios Delimanolis's observation, your *.java should not be in classes folder. It wll not hurt, if it is there; just that it shows you are not sure what should go where. Check this out: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yipeeee finally i resolved this issue.. by myself if anyone interested look here:

1. I found it from google that `"non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector defines on port 8080"` so i changed the port as "9999"..
2. I went this folder apache-tomcat-7.0.47=>>conf=>>`web.xml`(FILE)
   change the `param-value` as  `<param-value>true</param-value>` like this:

   [image: click here]

and then restart your server it will run successfully.

See output:

[image: click here]

Answer (score 0):

Your `doGet` method signature should be correct. `public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException`

You should access using the url `http://localhost:8080/YourAppName/test`

Also, in your `web.xml` configuration as Sotirios has said, make this change, `<servlet-class>bla.ServletDemo</servlet-class>`

Comment: After you make changes in web.xml, restart the server and make sure your url matches with the one I've provided.

Comment: What is the name of you web application project?

Comment: here is my URL http://localhost:8080/FirstServlet/test and my project name is "FirstServlet"

Comment: also i'm running this project on netbeans but unfortunately apachche showing an authentication user passoword .. i put "admin" as user name and password but it's showing as incorrect..

Comment: @user3135884 sorry, can't access images from this machine. Blocked in office :(